# Connect to hidden network in KUbuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I am trying to connect to a hidden (WPA2 protected) network. I cannot find a GUI way. I tried the following solutions from other questions:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan essid *name*                                 
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

and:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "Name"                                                                                                                                             
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :     
SET failed on device wlan0 ; No such device.
```

Also:

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network                                         
       description: Wireless interface              
       product: Wireless 3160                       
       vendor: Intel Corporation                    
       physical id: 0                               
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0                   
       logical name: wlp2s0                         
       version: 83                                  
       serial: a0:88:69:72:1c:08                    
       width: 64 bits                               
       clock: 33MHz                                 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless                   
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-32-generic firmware=17.608620.0 ip=192.168.43.81 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11                                   
       resources: irq:52 memory:b0a00000-b0a01fff
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously at some point in time the interface name changed and you did not realize it. The working command line solution is:

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan essid Name
```

which I realized by running `ifconfig` wthout any arguments.

I still don't have a GUI solution, but I can live with that.